# Circular reference in dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-5

I am creating a RESTful api in Net 5, according to the instructions I must create repositories and services that make use of them. The logic must be in the services.

The Services I have are:

SubGroupService
GroupsService

The problem I have is that I generated a circular reference since in GroupsService I need a method of SubGroupsService and SubGroupsService i need a method of GroupsService .

Injecting the GroupsService service into SubGroupsService there is no problem, but injecting SubGroupsService into GroupsService generates the circular reference.

Please can you tell me how to solve this type of problem, since I don't have much experience with dependency injection.

SubGroupService

```
public class SubGroupService: ISubGroupService
{       
    private readonly ISubGroupRepository _SubGroupRepository;
    private readonly IGroupService _GroupService;        
    public SubGroupService(
        ISubGroupRepository SubGroupRepository,
        IGroupService GroupService
    {          
        _SubGroupRepository = SubGroupRepository;
        _GroupService = GroupService;        
    }

    public async Task InsertSubGroupService(Subgroup subgroup)
    {
        var group = await _GroupService.GetGroupService(subgroup.idgroup);
        
        if (group != null)
        {
            await _SubGroupRepository.InsertSubGroupRepository(subgroup);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new BusinessException("This group not exists");
        }
    }

    public async Task<Subgroups> GetSubGroupService(int idgroup)
    {
        return await _SubGroupRepository.GetSubGroupRepository(idgroup);
    }
}
```

Group Service

```
public class GroupService : IGroupService
{
    private readonly ISubGroupService _SubGroupService;
    private readonly IGroupRepository _GroupRepository;
    public GroupService(
        ISubGroupService SubGroupService,
        IGroupRepository GroupRepository)
    {
        _SubGroupService = SubGroupService;
        _GroupRepository = GroupRepository;
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteGroupService(int Idgroup)
    {
        var existsSubGroup = await _SubGroupRepository(Idgroup);
        if(existsSubGroup == null)
        {
            return await _GroupRepository.DeleteGroupRepository(Idgroup);

        }
    }

    public async Task<Groups> GetGroupService(int Idgroup)
    {
        return await _GroupRepository.GetGroupRepository(Idgroup);
    }
}
```

Interfaces:

```
public interface IGroupService
{
    Task<Groups> GetGroupsService(int Idgroup);
    Task<bool> DeleteGroupService(int Idgroup);
}

public interface ISubGroupService
{
    Task<Subgroups> GetSubGroupService(int idsubgrupo);
    Task InsertSubgroupService(Subgroup subgroup);
}
```

Comment: What if `GroupService` implemented both `IGroupService` and `ISubGroupService`? Or is that not possible?

Comment: and why do you need  `_SubGroupRepository` in `SubGroupService` and so ...

Comment: `_SubGroupService` isn't used in your example. If a service method is just calling a repository method, why not just call the repository directly? Or move the implementation of that service to an extension method.

Comment: What if this is just a single service and a single interface? Not sure I fully understand what you want, but if this is a tree structure each group can have subgroups and each group be a subgroup. You could add a method to get the root group(s).

Comment: You shouldn't really be in this situation, if you have circular dependencies like this, your services likely are doing the wrong things, and your concerns are muddled. Which is another trap *young players* fall into playing the ill conceived and wrongly touted repository *hokey pokey*

Comment: @TheGeneral Hi, I think the problem started when I didn't want to implement the UnitOfWork pattern. Is there a pattern that allows me to use most of the code or repair these errors? Thank You.

Comment: [Section 6.3](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-6/section-6-3?origin=product-toc) of DIPP&P talks about Cyclic Dependencies, what's causing them and how to fix them. The chapter is behind a paywall, but you might be able to read just enough to understand how to fix them. Spoiler: you might want to split either SubGroupService or GroupService into multiple smaller classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use constructor injection in that case. You can switch to property injection:

```
public class SubGroupService: ISubGroupService
{       
    private readonly ISubGroupRepository _SubGroupRepository;
    public IGroupService GroupService { get; set; }
    public SubGroupService(
        ISubGroupRepository SubGroupRepository)
    {          
        _SubGroupRepository = SubGroupRepository;
    }

    // methods of the class
}

public class GroupService : IGroupService
{
    public ISubGroupService SubGroupService {get; set;}
    private readonly IGroupRepository _GroupRepository;
    public GroupService(
        IGroupRepository GroupRepository)
    {
        _GroupRepository = GroupRepository;
    }
    
    // methods of the class
}
```

You'll have to create the objects like this:

```
IGroupRepository groupRepository = new GroupRepository();
IGroupService groupService = new GroupService(groupRepository);
ISubGroupService subGroupService = new SubGroupService(groupRepository);
groupService.SubGroupSerivce = subGroupService;
subGroupService.GroupService = groupService;
```

Of course, creation of the objects is now much more complicated. You might put the creation into a facotry method to avoid errors:

```
public (IGroupService,ISubGroupService) CreateGroupAndSubGroupService()
{
   // code from above
}
```

And it is also advisable to add null checks, because someone might create the objects without initializing the service correctly.

Comment: Even though this answers the question, I think Allan should rethink their design before going down this route.

Comment: @M.Dennhardt The problem itself, I think I caused it when I didn't want to implement the UnitOfWork pattern. How do you recommend redoing this part of the service to avoid these errors? Thanks.